# OpenERP - Add fields only to some products inside a Category

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm setting up OpenERP v7. I know how to create modules and so on.

The problem is that not all the products will have the same fields. For example for T-shirts I would have Color, Size. But for belts I will have: Material, Length (as an example).

I know the option of using multi-variants but it's very very confusing. It creates a new column for *Dimension values* but then the *Name* of the product has also the *Dimension values* in it. It's very annoying.
Also, the access to the *Product Templates* is only accessible from the *Sales module*, so our Procurement department doesn't have access to it.

I would like more if a pre-defined template appears after a user selects the category of the product. Since products in same category will have the same field requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a better way to solve it, which is by using the module *product_custom_attributes*, downloadable from: https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/product_custom_attributes/

This module let's me create sets of attributes that can be later loaded into the product, I can also filtrate the products depending on the attribute value which is cool.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following.

Define all fields in your model (color, size, material etc.). Then hide the from views according to the product category.

To hide some field based on the category_id value you may try something like this:

```
<field name="some_field"
       attrs="{'invisible': [('category_id', 'not in', [1, 2, 3])]}"/>
```

Comment: Is this the only way? I'm afraid this will increase the database size since a lot of records will have empty fields as it doesn't apply to their category. If I do hide fields depending on the category selected, how can i do it? It will need to be done by __category_id__ instead of __category_name__ in case the user changes the name of the category.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the only acceptable way to do it. At least I don't see another one.
Please see my updated answer for an example how to hide some fields based on the category ids.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, I might modify it to just display if it's __in__ a category and if it's a __child_of__ a parent category. I can imagine this is going to become a huge work to set it up like this, but if it's the only way...